# Can't change previous user for App Store, Can't update apps

Tags: mac-appstore

There was a previous user before me using this Enterprise Mac. The administrator added my account and made me administrator too. But when I want to update XCode, it asks me for connexion with the previous user !
I can't change this field, it forces me to connect with the old user.

How can I change that please?

[image]

Doing a Sign Out didn't change anything. It is always associated to the previous account...

Comment: If the computer is controlled by your company, you will have to ask them. They should have cleared any previous user's data from it before assigning it to you.

Comment: Can you create a new Apple ID and disconnect the active Apple ID from System Preferences, then connect with the new Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the pervious version of Xcode installed on your Mac and install the latest one.

This was the only solution that worked for me when I forgot the account with which I downloaded Xcode, but it did take about 24 hours to work.

Comment: Can you clarifying your answer?  I’m trying to follow what you wrote, but the solution isn’t clear.

Comment: uninstall  the pervious Xcode installed on your Mac and  install new one

Comment: Please [Edit] your answer with this clarification.  I should have mentioned that in my first comment

Comment: You mean, update the last XCode Version? I always do updates, even big ones, and it didn't change

Comment: you should delete your XCode and then reinstall the latest version from AppStore